# what does format {0:x} mean?

Tags: c#

I came across this C# literal and was wondering what does it mean?

Especially, in the following case:

```
string.Format("{0:x}", byteArray[i]);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It means format the first argument (index 0) as hexadecimal: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8s7t687(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: To be precise, it means to apply the `"x"` format to the first argument.  In the case of a `byte` value, it formats the value as a lowercase hexadecimal.

Comment: Thanks for the the response and not being critical about asking a silly question...

Answer (score 0):

It means the first argument will be output as hexadecimal (in lowercase !!).
To output uppercase you could use "{0:X}".

Look msdn for more info about string formatting : [MSDN Custom string format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

This represents the `hexadecimal` format.